# Web Page Access Problem

Tags: c#, iis, error-handling

I am developing a web application using C#. I deployed the application in IIS. When 2 users access the same page in same time one user getting the result and the other getting the error. I don't know what's the problem.

Is any problem in IIS deployment or in my application.

**For your Informaion**
The Following Error Message wat i'm getting

Exception information: Exception type: DataAccessException Exception message: There was a problem creating the DataTable. CorpAct.DataAccess.ORADataFactory.CreateDataTable(DataRequest Request) at CRM.EHE.Database.DB_RRReport.getPortFolios(String strMonth, String strYear) in D:\Ranga\EHE Backup\CRM\CRM.EHE\CRM.EHE.Database\RRReport\DB_RRReport.cs:line 312 at

Comment: Please don't make substantial edits to your questions as this completely changes the context of other user's answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it's your code problem. You can have error if the page that you access is write some data to DataBase and you have data conflict, in that case you should use transaction.

Or you use a locks

Post your error text!

Answer (score 0):

If your page is accesable to someone it is unlikely that your problem lies within your IIS configuration when someone else is having trouble to view the page as well. You probably need to dive deeper into the error you get (which you didn't specify in your question by the way), to get the problem solved. Good luck!